# Hosting React/Redux Web Apps (front end)

Tags: reactjs, heroku, hosting, react-redux, web-hosting

One thing I do not quite understand yet is this. Say I have a website or single page app, made with React/Redux. Say I have no API calls or anything like this, so it's just the front-end I am talking about.

Do I have any restrictions when it comes to hosting?

People speak of Heroku & AWS here a lot, but as I understand it this concerns only the backend (?) Could I just host my React site with a 'traditional' provider or would I have to look out for something more specific?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no specific requirements for hosting a react JS webapp.

Let's say you're using webpack to build your webapp, it'll build a static javascript file that need to be served just like regular static assets.

So just the way you'd serve any other website that has static html/css/js assets.

That is the case when you've no special requirements. Now if you wish to build on the server you'd expect the server to run nodejs and have decent memory to support the build process. If you need to do caching/load balancing/rate limiting you'll have to use different required solutions.